# Constructing a Confidence Interval using the normal approximation of a poisson

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, normal-approximation

Letting Y₁ ... Yₙ ~ Pois (λ), this would approximate to N(λ,λ). Hence constructing a confidence interval with a 90% confidence level would be:

$$0.90 = (Z₀.₀₅ < \frac{Ȳ -λ}{\sqrtλ/n} < Z₀.₉₅) = (Ȳ - 1.645\sqrt\frac{λ}{n} < λ < Ȳ + 1.645\sqrt\frac{λ}{n})$$

meaning that the confidence interval would be: $$Ȳ ± 1.645\sqrt\frac{λ}{n}$$

So, why can the confidence interval also be expressed as: $$Ȳ ± 1.645\sqrt\frac{Ȳ}{n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that $\lambda$ is sufficiently large such that the normal approximation is valid. Even then, only the 2nd expression for the confidence interval for the mean is correct. Intuitively, it doesn't make sense for it to depend on the presumably-unknown parameter $\lambda$, which you'd be trying to estimate with $\bar{Y}$.

You can get this by correcting your expression for the confidence interval; i.e.

$$Pr\left[Z_{0.05} < \frac{\bar{Y} - \lambda}{\sqrt{S_Y / n}} < Z_{0.95}\right] = 0.90$$

where $S_y$ is your sample variance (i.e. $S_Y = \bar{Y}$). Simplify and you'll get the expected expression for a confidence interval.

Comment: The sample variance is not equal to the sample mean in general; rather, the MLE of the population variance would be the sample mean.

Comment: @Glen_b When you say population variance, you mean the population variance of the poisson. i.e. MLE: λ = Ȳ, which hence would give this expression Ȳ±1.645sqrt(Ȳn)

Comment: @hihihi1029 Yes, of the Poisson. The expression in the answer (with Y-bar put in place in the denominator) is fine in large samples, since the Z-score (with unknowns replaced by their MLEs) will be approximately normal. My only issue was in the phrasing underneath it (it's discussing the right thing but it's not quite correctly described). If you take the above answer and substitute in the correct quantities and make $\lambda$ the subject you will get the same expression as in your comment, except that the last term should be $\sqrt{\bar{Y}/n}$ (i.e. divided by n, not times n)

Comment: Ah. Right. A careless mistake on my part. Thanks for the succinct explanation